# Vim string (double quotes) operator

Tags: vim, ideavim

I found the following vim remaps and they work perfectly for selecting, deleting, choosing...everything in between parenthesis or brackets

```
onoremap b i[|               
onoremap p i(|
```

I tried getting the same done for strings but it does not work
`onoremap s i\"|`

I've tried mapping it to different key as well as using omap without success.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Better read `:help text-objects` instead of defining a bunch of custom mappings that save you exactly one key press.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the "re" in "onoremap" goes with "no" to make "nore", short for "non-recursive", not with "map". Thus, these are not "remaps", but "mappings" (or the uncommon "maps", if you really want).

Second, I am not sure where you got these from but the `|` doesn't appear to be an integral part of the mappings. The trailing spaces on the first line make it look like an attempt to handle inline comments as per `:help :map-comments`, but your sample doesn't include comments so this is puzzling. If you don't have a clear justification for those `|`s, you should remove them (and fix your trailing whitespace issues):

```
onoremap b i[
onoremap p i(
```

Third, doing the same for double-quoted strings is easy enough:

```
onoremap s i"
```

Note that the risk is high of overriding useful motions, here. You are already doing that with the first mapping (`:help b`) and you will probably stumble on other cases as you add more text object "shortcuts". The whole idea doesn't seem very good to me.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
onoremap s i"
```

tested with vim 9.0